Error running pod install (when trying to run Flutter app target platform macOS or iOS)
Whenever I try to run my flutter app for target platform macOS I get the following output in the debug console where its says Error running pod install:
Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in debug mode...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-RunnerTests`: (``)

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `FlutterMacOS` from `Flutter/ephemeral`
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_foundation` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_foundation/darwin`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- ffi_c (LoadError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.17.0-arm64-darwin/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.17.0-arm64-darwin/lib/ffi.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.16.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.1/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in `refresh_metadata'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:173:in `repo_information'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:77:in `stack'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:24:in `report'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.17.0-arm64-darwin/lib/2.6/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.17.0-arm64-darwin/lib/2.6/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (arm64), need (x86_64h))) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.17.0-arm64-darwin/lib/2.6/ffi_c.bundle (LoadError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.17.0-arm64-darwin/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.16.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.1/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in `refresh_metadata'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:173:in `repo_information'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:77:in `stack'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:24:in `report'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- ffi_c (LoadError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.17.0-arm64-darwin/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.17.0-arm64-darwin/lib/ffi.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.16.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.1/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in `refresh_metadata'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:393:in `source_with_url'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:22:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:179:in `block in sources'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `map'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `sources'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1081:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1080:in `resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:125:in `analyze'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.17.0-arm64-darwin/lib/2.6/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.17.0-arm64-darwin/lib/2.6/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (arm64), need (x86_64h))) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.17.0-arm64-darwin/lib/2.6/ffi_c.bundle (LoadError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.17.0-arm64-darwin/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.16.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.1/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in `refresh_metadata'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:393:in `source_with_url'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:22:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:179:in `block in sources'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `map'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `sources'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1081:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1080:in `resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:125:in `analyze'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error: Error running pod install

Exited (1).

I already had some trouble installing cocoapods in the first place.
When I ran sudo gem install cocoapods in terminal (zsh) I got the following:
Fetching cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5.gem
Fetching cocoapods-search-1.0.1.gem
Fetching cocoapods-downloader-2.1.gem
Fetching cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-core-1.15.2.gem
Fetching cocoapods-try-1.2.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-1.15.2.gem
Successfully installed cocoapods-try-1.2.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-search-1.0.1
Successfully installed cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-downloader-2.1
Successfully installed cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    The last version of drb (>= 0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 2.0.6. Try installing it with `gem install drb -v 2.0.6` and then running the current command again
    drb requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.

So then I ran sudo gem install drb -v 2.0.6:
Fetching drb-2.0.6.gem
Successfully installed drb-2.0.6
Parsing documentation for drb-2.0.6
Installing ri documentation for drb-2.0.6
Done installing documentation for drb after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

followed by sudo gem install cocoapods and got the following:
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    The last version of activesupport (>= 5.0, < 8) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 6.1.7.8. Try installing it with `gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.8` and then running the current command again
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 3.1.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.

So I ran sudo gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.8:
Fetching activesupport-6.1.7.8.gem
Successfully installed activesupport-6.1.7.8
Parsing documentation for activesupport-6.1.7.8
Installing ri documentation for activesupport-6.1.7.8
Done installing documentation for activesupport after 2 seconds
1 gem installed

followed by sudo gem install cocoapods and got:
Successfully installed cocoapods-core-1.15.2
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.15.2
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-core-1.15.2
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-core-1.15.2
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.15.2
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-1.15.2
Done installing documentation for cocoapods-core, cocoapods after 3 seconds
2 gems installed

With this done, I assume cocoapods should be installed and in working order. So I tried to run the app with target platform macOS and this is where it didn't work (getting "Error running pod install"). After some searching around I tried the steps mentioned here:
flutter clean
rm -Rf macos/Pods
rm -Rf macos/.symlinks
rm -Rf macos/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf macos/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
flutter pub get
cd macos
pod install

Then I tried running the app again via vscode ui and via terminal (I tried zsh AND bash) in vscode and it still get the same error.
Here is my flutter doctor -v:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on macOS 12.7.6 21H1320 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
• Flutter version 3.24.3 on channel stable at /Users/jan/src/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 2663184aa7 (3 weeks ago), 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
• Engine revision 36335019a8
• Dart version 3.5.3
• DevTools version 2.37.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/jan/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11572160)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14C18
! Flutter recommends a minimum Xcode version of 15.
Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
• CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11572160)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2023.2.1)
• IntelliJ at /Users/jan/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.app
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] VS Code (version 1.94.0)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.98.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.7.6 21H1320 darwin-x64
• Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 125.0.6422.61

[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.


Seems like cocoapods installed with preinstalled system ruby – that's not great and been reported many times as unreliable way.
Try installing with brew instead:

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods – to remove previous installation
brew install cocoapods

If using brew is impossible in your environment – you still need to avoid system installation of Ruby. For this, try to use rbenv and install cocoapods with separate ruby

Doing it with brew worked. I ran brew install cocoapods and then had to run brew link --overwrite cocoapods for it to work.
